# MapKit doesn't center on right location

Tags: ios, swift, location, mapkit

I have a problem with my MapKit in Swift. I want it to center on a specific coordinate, but the default center doesn't change at all. The first (and most important part of) my viewController.swift file looks like this:

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var map : MKMapView! = MKMapView()
    var locManager:CLLocationManager!

    @IBOutlet var txtUsername: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var txtPassword: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        var centerCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(41.8796677, -87.6198131)

        var mapSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)

        var mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(centerCoordinate, mapSpan)

        self.map.setRegion(mapRegion, animated: true)

        locManager = CLLocationManager()
        locManager.delegate = self
        locManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        map.showsUserLocation = true
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
```

What could be the reason that the center of the map is not changed by the variable 'centerCoordinate'?

Comment: why is your code before the viewDidLoad? Also can you update the question with an image of the mapview

Comment: you should probably call your code in ViewDidAppear() because you will know for a fact you have the user location

Answer (score 1):

There are func's that are called automatically when the map is in use.  One of them is

func mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap(mapView: MKMapView)

Try doing this.

```
  func mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap(mapView: MKMapView) {
    map.setRegion(mapRegion, animated: true)
}
```

If this doesn't work type func mapView and look in the list and find one you think might but I feel this is where it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

In ViewController.swift, find viewDidLoad and add the following to the end of the method:

```
// set initial location in Honolulu
let initialLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 21.282778, longitude: -157.829444)
```

You’ll use this to set the the starting coordinates of the map view to a point in Honolulu.
When you are trying to tell the map what to display, you can’t just give a latitude and longitude. That’s enough to center the map, but you need to specify the rectangular region to display to get a correct zoom level too.
Add the following constant and helper method to the class:

```
let regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 1000
func centerMapOnLocation(location: CLLocation) {
  let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate, 
    regionRadius * 2.0, regionRadius * 2.0)
  mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
}
```

The location argument is the center point. The region will be have north-south and east-west spans based on a distance of regionRadius – you set this to 1000 meters (1 kilometer), which is a little more than half a mile. You then use regionRadius * 2.0 here, because that works well for plotting the public artwork data in the JSON file.
setRegion tells mapView to display the region. The map view automatically transitions the current view to the desired region with a neat zoom animation, with no extra code required!
Back in `viewDidLoad`, add the following line to the end of the method:

```
centerMapOnLocation(initialLocation)
```

This will call the helper method to zoom into `initialLocation` on startup.
Build and run the app, and now it should zoom in to the heart of Waikiki :]

Font: http://www.raywenderlich.com/90971/introduction-mapkit-swift-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5.

In the `MKMapViewDelegate`, I recommend using the `regionDidChangeAnimated` method and setting the region of the `mapView` based on the user's coordinate. Change the span according to your use case.

```
extension MapViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
        mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(center: userLocation.coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1)), animated: true)
    }
}
```